# Dynamic associative arrays

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

```
cert_list=()
env_var=( "lbjk1" "lbjk2" )

for id1 in ${env_var[@]}; do
    declare -A lj_cert
    lj_cert[CONFIG_FILE]="hello_$id1"
    cert_list+=(lj_cert)
done


declare -n cert
for cert in "${cert_list[@]}"; do
    echo ${cert[CONFIG_FILE]}
done
```

I get the following output

```
hello_lbjk2
hello_lbjk2
```

But the expected output is

```
hello_lbjk1
hello_lbjk2
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're storing the `hello_$id1` strings in a single location, `lj_cert[CONFIG_FILE]`. It can only hold one value.

Comment: Can you explain your underlying goal? This seems rather complicated and I wonder if there's a simpler way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I a trying to store the values in cert_list array declared above. I later have to append more values to cert_list. But for now, just the hello_lbjk1 and hello_lbjk2? Can this be achieved by creating a dynamic array creation? like declare -A lj_cert_$id1?

Comment: What are you trying to do at a higher level? What's the meaning of these values and what are you doing with them? You have problem *X* and you think the solution is *Y*; I'd like to know what *X* is. See: [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: My aim is to create a dynamic associativce array using declare -A lj_cert_$id1 so i get two dynamic associative arrays which can be appended to cert_list. That is the only requirement I have. I just need to use this in an existing code base.

Comment: Are you trying to get 2-dimensional arrays? Bash doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to explain what is happening in your script, hope this'll help.

```
cert_list=()
env_var=( "lbjk1" "lbjk2" )

for id1 in ${env_var[@]}; do
    declare -A lj_cert # move 'declare' out of loop, it's requqired only once    

    lj_cert[CONFIG_FILE]="hello_$id1" # here you are inserting new data
                                      # in the same array item lj_cert[CONFIG_FILE]
                                      # in the end value will be 'hello_lbjk2'

    cert_list+=(lj_cert) # and here you are appending cert_list with the same string 'lj_cert'
done


declare -n cert # from declare help: make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value
for cert in "${cert_list[@]}"; do  # all values in this array are the same 'lj_cert'
    echo ${cert[CONFIG_FILE]}      # 'cert' will always reference to lj_cert, 
done                               # and since index in lj_cert the same (CONFIG_FILE)
                                   # the output is also the same 'hello_lbjk2'
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the following shell to see if it meets the requirements：

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cert_list=()
env_var=( "lbjk1" "lbjk2" )

for id1 in ${env_var[@]}; do
    declare -A lj_cert
    lj_cert['CONFIG_FILE']="hello_${id1}"
    cert_list+=(${lj_cert[@]})
done

for cert in "${cert_list[@]}"; do
    echo ${cert[CONFIG_FILE]}
done
```

Comment: This is pointless: `cert` will be a scalar in your code, and you can't use array indexing on it.